# how to open only whatsapp application when click on a hyperlink/image/button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, whatsapp

A code required for html website, when user open my website from mobile device and click on hyper link/image/button, then the link should open only whatsapp application.

I only need to open whatsapp application when user click on a link in my html website. that's it.

please share the code.

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to open whatsapp app when user click on the link. Edit according to your need

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Whatsapp</a>
```