# Clicking a link in mobile website should open whatsapp app

Tags: javascript, html, css, whatsapp

I dont want to share text in whatsapp, just want to open whatsapp app on click I tried

```
<a href="whatsapp://" class="btn whatsapp-btn btn-outline whatsapp-outline btn-block" >Create group</a>
```

Referred couple of links [how to open only whatsapp application when click on a hyperlink/image/button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885105/how-to-open-only-whatsapp-application-when-click-on-a-hyperlink-image-button) also
[Whatsapp html call link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243724/whatsapp-html-call-link)

But couldn’t get the exact answer.

Answer (score 4):

From [Whatsapp documentation](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012):

> WhatsApp provides a custom URL scheme to interact with WhatsApp:
>
> If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a
>   pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so.
>   Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open
>   WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input
>   field with the specified text.

So, this should work:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=YoYoYo" class="bla">Whatsapp link</a>
```

And if i'm lucky, also this! (when clicked from mobile device...)

Comment: I dont want to share anything, clicking on link should just open the whatApp app on mobile